# Наше устройство либо геолокационные сервысы сохраняют ли всю историю о нашей местоположении?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, геолокация, ос

Наше устройство либо геолокационные сервисы(например Googlemaps  и тд ) сохраняют ли все данные  о нашей местоположении?то есть все места где мы пробывали за неделю, месяц, в течении года и больше  сохраняются?И как можно удалять  все это и сделать  телефон как новенький?

Comment: «телефон как новенький» делается штатной функцией сброса до заводских настроек. Всё остальное хранится в вашем аккаунте Google и к телефону не имеет отношения

Comment: Ну вообще выборочно они собирают такую инфу, но они не признаются, и не дают её кому попало. Но вы можете накатать на себя телегу во все инстанции вроде АНБ. И спустя период времени запросить у гугла местоположение за неделю, месяц, может инфы соберут и за годы.

Comment: Вытащить/заменить память из телефона можно используя реболинг. А инфу с чипа выкачать можно программатором jtag. Но инфа зашифрована, а ключ лежит в сейфах у Сергея Брина и Ларри Пейджа.

Comment: @andreymal  а third party приложения которые установлены имеют доступ к этим данным ? ситуация : 2 смартфоны  в определенный момент времени пересикались друг с другом и имели одинаковый маршрут .Какой то "X" third party приложение которое имеет доступ к местоположению был установлен на обоих смартфонах .Так это приложение может получить историю нашей местоположении и выяснить  связ между двух устройств?

Comment: @DiD  а слежка постоянна? сохраняются ли только  те места которые определились  во время использования приложении или в фоновом режиме  всегда собираются данние о местоположеннии .  И какие данные собираются когда геолокация выключено ?

Comment: доступные пользователям данные не сохраняются при отключенной геолокации. Но сам аппаратный регистратор конечно собирает и передаёт данные на вышки постоянно. Для этого смартфону не нужны не симкарты, ни соединение с интернетом. И уж тем более не нужны никакие права доступа. У них там свои алгоритмы шифрования и свои протоколы передачи данных.

Comment: @DiD  а где хранятся данные ? на сарверах Google  ? И  third party приложения которые установлены на телефоне имеют доступ к этим данным ? Такая ситуация : 2 смартфоны в определенный момент времени пересикались друг с другом и имели одинаковый маршрут .Какой то "X" third party приложение которое имеет доступ к местоположению был установлен на обоих смартфонах .Так это приложение может получить историю нашей местоположении и выяснить связ между двух устройств?

Comment: @Jacewerlock приложения к этим данным не имеют доступа, разумеется, никакого api для просмотра этих данных не предусмотрено. Подсистема работает полностью автономно. Даже система питания работает независимо от аккумулятора смартфона и продолжает работать, даже после извлечения аккумулятора из смартфона. И только спустя несколько суток после извлечения смартфон останавливает вещание. Никто на Земле (кроме нескольких десятков человек) точно не знает, какие именно данные смартфон рассылает в обход пользовательского соглашения.

Comment: @Jacewerlock куда идут эти данные - тоже не понятно. Скорее всего, они хранятся во всех организациях, которые их слушают и собирают. Это совсем не обязательно серверы гугл. Сами протоколы GSM проприетарны и многие моменты засекречены даже для самого гугла.

Comment: @DiD а в самом устройстве  не хранятся  эти данние откуда могли бы брать  third party приложение?

Comment: Если устройство никогда не получало рут-прав, то сторонние приложения не могут собирать эту информацию без уведомления пользователя. Но производитель мог добавить своих жучков в прошивку.